# Kube Prometheus Stack Helm Not Working - Many to Many error

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have installed the kube prometheus stack helm chart. The chart appears to install on my 3 node Kubernetes cluster (1.27.3) without issues. All the deployments and pods seems to enter a ready state. I port forwarded the prometheus pod and attempted to connect but was not able to.

When I review the logs from the prometheus pod it seems that there is an error or warning that something is wrong with the rule set it generated:

```
ts=2023-07-15T22:26:26.110Z caller=manager.go:663 level=warn component="rule manager" file=/etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0/default-prometheus-kube-prometheus-kubernetes-system-kubelet-e76e1f61-e704-4f1c-a9f8-87d91012dd7c.yaml group=kubernetes-system-kubelet name=KubeletPodStartUpLatencyHigh index=5 msg="Evaluating rule failed" rule="alert: KubeletPodStartUpLatencyHigh\nexpr: histogram_quantile(0.99, sum by (cluster, instance, le) (rate(kubelet_pod_worker_duration_seconds_bucket{job=\"kubelet\",metrics_path=\"/metrics\"}[5m])))\n  * on (cluster, instance) group_left (node) kubelet_node_name{job=\"kubelet\",metrics_path=\"/metrics\"}\n  > 60\nfor: 15m\nlabels:\n  severity: warning\nannotations:\n  description: Kubelet Pod startup 99th percentile latency is {{ $value }} seconds\n    on node {{ $labels.node }}.\n  runbook_url: https://runbooks.prometheus-operator.dev/runbooks/kubernetes/kubeletpodstartuplatencyhigh\n  summary: Kubelet Pod startup latency is too high.\n" err="found duplicate series for the match group {instance=\"192.168.2.10:10250\"} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{__name__=\"kubelet_node_name\", endpoint=\"https-metrics\", instance=\"192.168.2.10:10250\", job=\"kubelet\", metrics_path=\"/metrics\", namespace=\"kube-system\", node=\"kubenode03\", service=\"prometheus-prime-kube-prom-kubelet\"}, {__name__=\"kubelet_node_name\", endpoint=\"https-metrics\", instance=\"192.168.2.10:10250\", job=\"kubelet\", metrics_path=\"/metrics\", namespace=\"kube-system\", node=\"kubenode03\", service=\"prometheus-kube-prometheus-kubelet\"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side
```

I am a newbie at prometheus so am unsure what to look for or how to troubleshoot this. Can someone help me understand:

1. What is this error complaining about?
2. How would I fix this error?

It appears that it is something in the cube-system namespace but I only have 3 pods in that namespace all with unique names:

CoreDNS
Local Path Provisioner
metrics-server

I appreciate any help or advice on how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this error complaining about?

Problem lies within your expression:

```
histogram_quantile(0.99, 
 sum by (cluster, instance, le) (
  rate(
   kubelet_pod_worker_duration_seconds_bucket{job="kubelet",metrics_path="/metrics"}
   [5m])))
* on (cluster, instance) group_left (node) kubelet_node_name{job="kubelet",metrics_path="/metrics"}
> 60
```

It seems like there are multiple metrics on the both sides of `on` with the same values of labels `cluster` and `instance`. It constitutes many-to-many relation, and Prometheus doesn't allow those.

> How would I fix this error?

Go to Prometheus' web ui, execute both parts of you on clause. You'll see labelsets produced by them. Correct your on clause, so that no many-to-many relations occur.

I'm not familiar with this exact metrics, so it's hard to say more specific what to look on.

Comment: This is a fresh install of the helm chart and I did not create any rules manually. It creates a number of what are supposed to be default rules. I have posted on their discussions section also.

When I try and connect to the server it drops the connection..

Answer (score 1):

I did more searching around and I found this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/635#issuecomment-774771566

It seems that I had a left over prometheus service from a previous failed install that the helm uninstall did not delete. It seems this was a duplicate. Once I deleted this everything started working.